# Вывести на экран индексы элементов массива которые составляют определенную сумму

Tags: java, массивы

Суть в том что бы вывести на экран элементы которые составляют сумму какого то заданного числа. Навел пример для поиска таких чисел, если брать во внимание что искать сумму всего 2 элементов.

```
public void findElement(int[] array, int sum){
for(int i = 0; i<array.lenght; i++){
for(int j = i+1; j<array.lenght; j++){
if((array[i] + array[j]) == sum){
System.out.println(array[i]+" "+array[j]);
}}
}
```

А как к примеру найти сумму состоящую из 3 и более элементов?

Comment: это ли не https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Задача_о_рюкзаке ?

Comment: У вас алгоритм неверный. Он может вывести один и тот же элемент, если этот элемент * 2 == summ. Также вы выводите пару дважды. Во избежание - `for(j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)`.

Comment: И вообще - ваш код не запустится.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, по поводу вывода одинаковых элементов. Сейчас исправлю вывод что бы был рабочим)

Comment: @AndrewBystrov не знал об этой задаче, спасибо, ее решение можно применить к моей. Буду разбираться :D